# How can I auto restart compile project in Visual Studio when my code has change?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, restart, application-restart

How can I auto restart compile project in Visual Studio when my code has change?
When I am afk. My code in Node.cs will change very often but i need to click this every time

[Restart Botton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W63CL.png)
I need to make it auto restart debug when code in Node.cs have change
Thank you!!

Comment: How are you changing the code while afk?

Comment: Yes my algorithm do it. It is a machine learning @NetMage

Comment: @Oat, Why not use the Edit and Continue without stopping debugging or restart the compiler?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue

Comment: thank you @JackZhai-MSFT im using it but program still need to restart(ctrl+shift+f5) for compile new appear code

Comment: I try to use code for close and open my console app again when new code appear but it doesn't work because debug not update to .exe

Comment: @Oat, Maybe you could share us a simple sample about how you change the code in your side,  my understanding is that if you were debugging your app with a breakpoint(it is hit), you could edit your code without stopping debugging if you enable the E&C, and it will update your code unless you edit the code which was called before your breakpoint is hit. But if you have to stop debug during you edit the code, you could change the build option under TOOLS->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run, you could select Always build if your projects are out of date.

Comment: @Oat, Any update for this issue?